# Automatic inventory based system for construction company

Tags: database, automation, inventory

I work for a cement contracting company. I need a program that already does this or a push in the right direction for a software that keeps track of all inventories that is stored at the main warehouse. Vehicles, lumber, power tools, hand tools, various types of equipment. I need it so the crew leads can use a basic app on their phones or website they can log into and pick which inventory they need for certain job sites. This would then be sent to the database where it would deduct the quantity of materials from the main warehouse or if it was a tool, put the tool out of service until they are done using it. This also needs to create a ticket or invoice automatically and sent to delivery drivers email showing the list of materials for which job sites so the delivery drivers can print them in the morning without any instruction from the shop manager.

I've tried Odoo but can't seem to quite get the hang of it. I first started organizing with the Odoo inventory app.

Answer (score 0):

An asset management system that you could try out, even though more popular for IT assets is [Snipe-IT](https://snipeitapp.com/).

- There is an open source version.
- It can run on a webserver, so users and login via devices.
- It can handle check-outs/check-ins, email notifications, low inventory reports, etc.
- You can try out the [demo here](https://demo.snipeitapp.com/login).

The bit where you may have to build some customised code is may be the Invoices.